# Wordpress - How to add a local font in my child theme

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to add downloaded `fonts` in my child theme? . 
Because I'm using google fonts and `render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content` is my problem every time I test my site `pagespeed insights`

Comment: Have you tried to download fonts directly instead of embed from google fonts?

Comment: I tried, but how can i call the downloaded fonts to my theme?

Answer (score 0):

You have to unzip font downloaded by GoogleFonts

Place them in theme folder (eg:  wp-content/themes/_MY_THEME_/fonts/)

Open your style.css file and add following code:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Font-Name';
  src: url('fonts/Font-Name.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
  url('fonts/Font-Name.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/Font-Name.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/Font-Name.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

where "Font-Name" will be replaced by name of the font downloaded

Comment: thanks, I'll try this, is this also possible using google fonts? like raleway, droid, etc

Comment: Of course, you can download directly from GoogleFonts.
please, if it work..give me a vote ;-)